# PayPal Checkout frontend and backend communication security

Tags: paypal

I want to use Paypal on my web application. I use ReactJS for the frontend and Spring boot for the backend. The thing is that I successfully connected the frontend to Paypal and Paypal is able to confirm my payment back with status and transaction number.

However, after I receive the confirmation about the payment I need to perform a certain action which involves sending something on the backend. But I am concerned about the security side of these actions. Because what if someone will just post the request on my API without even performing the transaction with Paypal?

My first idea was to send a request to Paypal and then after confirmation and transaction ID send the transaction ID on the backend and on the backend call Paypal's transaction API and query for the given transaction API so I have confirmation that the transaction exists, however, Paypal's transaction API has a massive delay and I cannot get in a few minutes so I don't know what I should do.

I wanted to have it fully automatic, so the user gets an immediate response and can work with the service he bought. It seems to me that my only choice is to manually check the payments and if they are valid, manually perform these actions.

Is there any best practice for how this should be done or any idea? Or is there a way to ensure that my API will consume requests from my frontend?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Better to follow the way PayPal tell to integrate their API, they already thought about your concern AND have more experience than you have. Or maybe you can ask PayPal.

Answer (score 1):

Use a server-side integration. Create two routes, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return only JSON data.

Pair those two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

When you do the capture action on your server, verify that the capture was successful and for the correct amount and that there is a PayPal transaction ID, to then store in your database for accounting/refund purposes. And respond to the client with the JSON indicating success, or propagate any errors to it.